# numpy: why array multiplication is commutative?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm rather new to python and really new for numpy.
I realized that with numpy I can multiply arrays in all configuration:
row*column, column*row, column*column, row*row.

What does it mean?
I thought that this is matrix multiplication and the only legal is row*column,
or column*row and result is zero dimensional or two dimensional.
I'm confused with this operation.

Comment: numpy operations are usually element-wise. Please also read the [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to understand what happens with arrays of different dimensions.

Comment: Oh, and if you need matrix multiplication, try something like `np.matrix(a) * np.matrix(b)`, or [`np.dot(a,b)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that this is matrix multiplication

Unless you're using `matrix` objects or the `dot` method/function, it's not. It's elementwise multiplication, with some additional handling known as [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for dimensions that don't match. If you want matrix multiplication, use

```
numpy.dot(A, B)
```

You can also use `matrix` objects instead of `ndarray`s, but the inconsistencies they cause can be annoying to work with. You need to know what operations will return a matrix if given a matrix and what will always return an array, and `A[x][y]` won't work, and there are even more little issues that will screw you up.

Comment: `numpy.dot(A, B)` can now [be abbreviated](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/#abstract) `A @ B` (it calls `matmul`, not `dot`, but in the present case it's what we want)

Answer (score 3):

Numpy arrays are N-dimensional grid data, and most of their binary operations perform elementwise scalar operations. `a * b` yields `a[i,j,k] * b[i,j,k]`. If the arrays are of different shapes, numpy will attempt to [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the smaller array into something that still makes sense, then perform the elementwise operation.

Numpy matrices are a separate datastructure. They are always 2-dimensional and obey all the rules you learned in linear algebra.